# ESLint detect undefined property of an import

Tags: javascript, eslint

ESLint does not seem to detect unresolved object properties.

For example, I am importing a module, which is exporting a couple of methods. And I am calling an undefined method on this module, e.g.:

```js
import * as app from "./app";

app.undefinedMethod();
```

Now, PHPStorm is detecting these issues ("unresolved function or method"), but ESLint is not. How come? I tried looking for an option, but I didn't find anything. I found a Github feature request that was later aborted.

Is it really that complicated to get the list of exported symbols and detect the use of a non-exported symbol?

Is there an option that I did not find?

Here is my config:

```
"extends" : [
    "eslint:recommended"
],
"rules" : {
    "no-shadow": "error",
    "no-var": "error",
    "prefer-const": "error"
},
```

Is there something wrong with it?

Also, since going to ESLint 8 (from 6), I noticed it is now very (!!) slow (30 seconds for a couple dozen of files, against like 5 seconds with version 6), maybe I am doing something the wrong way?

Thank you kindly,